# How to ask for infinite inputs until user replies with desired input? (totalBill > 10)

Tags: python-3.x

My code should iterate to the else statement since totalBill is -1. However, there is no output at all. I have written a code similar to this previously where I used the concept of appending lists. I tried getting inspiration from that code but it did not work.

```
#Tip Calculator
totalBill = -1
while totalBill > 0:
    tip = int(input("What percentage would you like to tip? 10, 12, 15?"))
    if tip == 12 or tip == 10 or tip == 15:
        totalPeople = int(input("How many people should split the bill?"))
        eachBill = (totalBill + (totalBill * (tip / 100))) / totalPeople
        print(f"Each person must pay {eachBill}.")
    # else:
    #     print(f"Please enter a valid tip.")
    #     tip = int(input("What percentage would you like to tip? 10, 12, 15?"))
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid total bill.")
    totalBill = int(input("How much was the total bill?"))
```

The code that I got inspiration from:

```
#Appending to a list
#buyComputer.py

availableParts = ["Computer", "Monitor", "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Speaker"]
choice = "-"
computerParts = []

while choice != '0':
    if choice in "12345":
        print(f"Adding {availableParts[int(int(choice) - 1)]} to the list.")
        #index =
        #indexValue =
        if choice == '1':
            computerParts.append(availableParts[0])
        elif choice == '2':
            computerParts.append(availableParts[1])
        elif choice == '3':
            computerParts.append(availableParts[2])
        elif choice == '4':
            computerParts.append(availableParts[3])
        elif choice == '5':
            computerParts.append(availableParts[4])
    else:
        print("In order to start this program, please choose a valid input within 1-5.")
        # for part in availableParts: #Iterating though a list to display all the elements of a list
        #     position = availableParts.index(part) + 1
        #     print(position, part)
        for position, part in enumerate(availableParts):
            print(f"{position + 1}: {part}")
    choice = input("What part do you want to shop for?")
print(f"Your final list of items contains {computerParts}")
```

Comment: Your `while` condition itself is not met because totalBill is -1. Maybe you want to take the input for totalBill once before entering the loop too?

Answer (score 1):

You never enter the while loop because it's condition to enter is total bill being greater than 0